# kafka consumer Connection check

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to check the connection of the Kafka consumer at a remote location.

It is possible to determine whether the consumer is allocated to the partition.

At a remote location, i can get detailed information about the topic from the Kafka broker.

But can the consumer guarantee that the consumer is able to receive the message that the consumer is matched to the topic's partition?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Kafka Rest Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html) to determine whether a partition has been assigned to the consumer or not.

I think, Kafka Rest Proxy have all functionality which you are looking for.